# jquery . is it possible to hide a dynamic generated object (tr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my script to generate

```
var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
$('#users-table > tbody:first').append("< tr id='"+milliseconds.toString()+"'><td>newuser</td>  <td><a href=\"javascript:remove_user('"+milliseconds.toString()+"')\"  ><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></td>   </tr>");
```

And I use this piece of code to hide

```
function remove_user(tr_id){
        $("#"+tr_id).hide();

 }
```

but it seems not working properly (After I clicked the Icon It is supposed to be hided. But the new user is still showing up). Is something I am missing?

Comment: Your function accepts 3 parameters, you need to use the third one.

Comment: Define "not working properly". Also, purely numeric IDs are bad, IIRC.

Comment: I just updated original post :)

Comment: @DaveNewton After I clicked the Icon It is supposed to be hided. But the new user is still showing up

Comment: Maybe try changing `< tr` to `<tr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space in your `tr` is throwing things off.  Remove it and it will work.

[jsFiddle not working](http://jsfiddle.net/fcGHD/1/)

[jsFiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/fcGHD/)

The problem seems to be with jQuery parsing the HTML:

```
$("< tr><td></td></tr>")[0].tagName //TD instead of TR
```

Comment: I was just about to post this, then I saw you already did (and explained). You might want to file a bugreport since it hasn't been fixed yet, even in the latest jQuery release. Nevertheless, always avoid spaces in weird, unexpected places like this.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers A problem caused by malformed HTML will likely be marked as wontfix. The native `document.getElementById` will not work in this case either.

Comment: @Boaz Ah, well I guess that's a good reason not to 'fix' it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to tr while creating it. And on click of a button refer to the td using the class and apply display : none to it .

```
    var milliseconds = new Date().getTime(); $('#users-table > tbody:first').append("< tr class="mango" id='"+milliseconds.toString()+"'><td>newuser</td> <td><a href=\"javascript:remove_user('"+milliseconds.toString()+"')\" ><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></td> </tr>");
 $("#btn").click(function(){ $("tr.mango").css("display","none"); });
```

Comment: in that case var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
    $('#users-table > tbody:first').append("< tr class="mango" id='"+milliseconds.toString()+"'><td>newuser</td>  <td><a href=\"javascript:remove_user('"+milliseconds.toString()+"')\"  ><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></td>   </tr>"); 


$("#btn").click(function(){
$("td.mango").css("display","none");
});

Comment: Update your answer then... :) But @Dennis is correct. The problem is with the redundant space.